# Can not display external page in <iframe>, not an X_FRAME issue

Tags: iframe

I have an iframe - the iframe works when the src points to a page on the same server, allowing me to embed pages.

The same iframe will not allow me to embed pages from another server.  I have tried different src= pages and different browsers on Windows, OSX and Linux.  I have tried hard-coding the src attribute and setting it programatically.

I haven't worked w html for years and know click-jacking has caused some hosts to disallow their content but am confident this is not the issue.

```
<iframe src='myPage.html' name='i' id='i'></iframe>
```

works as expected

```
<iframe src='http://theirServer/theirPage.html' name='i' id='i'>
</frame>
```

does not work as expected

Comment: Can you ellaborate on "will not allow me to embed pages" what exactly are you seeing? There are cross-scripting limitations that can keep the parent and iframe from talking, but simply embedding an iframe should not be an issue.

Comment: While I don't believe this is your issue, your closing tag is wrong...should be </iframe> not </frame>

Answer (score 0):

Not all sites allow you to embed them via iframe (such as google).  if using Chrome, check your console.  If you have an error like "Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." then the site does not allow you to embed it.

Basically if the site uses the header X-Frame-Options, and has it set to SAMEORIGIN, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: You could possibly use a standard frame element and then set it's innerHTML via Javascript and pulling the site content manually.